# Calculate in loops

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following line-up:

```
Calculated Hours:     164
Calculated Holidays:   20
Available Holidays:    10% of 164 = 16.4
Diff Holidays:         -3.6
```

Now, because the Diff Holidays are negativ, I have to reduce Calculated Holidays: 164 - 3.6 = 161.4

But this reduce concludes, that Available Holidays are also reduced to 10% of 161.4 = 16.14

The new Diff Holidays is now 20 - 16.14 = 3.86 what concludes, that I have to reduce the calculated hours to 164 - 3.86 = 160.14 what one more time conculdes that the calculated holidays are reduced etc.

Now my question: Can I calculate the right reducing of calculated hours with one step? Or do I have to try it in the described steps?

PS: I have no idea, what Tag to use ...

Comment: it seems that you want to reduce Calculated Hours but not Calculated Holidays.

Comment: how is Calculated Holidays calculated?

Comment: Calculated Holidays are a fixed value. Perhaps the naming is not perfect. I want only reduce Calculated Hours if the Diff Holidays is negativ. The reduce of calculated Holidays is changing the diff holidays which triggers a next change of calculated hours etc.

Comment: you wrote "I have to reduce Calculated Holidays" but I think this means "I have to reduce Calculated Hours"

Comment: you have an error in your calculation: 164-3.6=160.4, what is the source of your problrm?

Comment: you should open a spreadsheet an calculate a lot of steps of your problems